# Duplicating data in db while saving (Django form)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I've created a form that when enter page loads initial data from json file and then I can edit and save the data in the same form. All work perfect but every time I press submit button database accepts two rows of same data. Any help  appreciated.

views.py

```
def form_save_and_edit(request, id=None, template_name='create.html'):

""" referring data from "model_from_json()",
making data visible within another function """

func = model_from_json()

""" savind and editing form data in the same form """

form = UserDataForm(request.POST)
if request.POST:

    updated_field = form.save()
    last_name = request.session['last_name'] = updated_field.last_name
    first_name = request.session['first_name'] = updated_field.first_name
    email = request.session['email'] = updated_field.email
    skype = request.session['skype'] = updated_field.skype

    form = UserDataForm({
    'last_name': last_name,
    'first_name': first_name,
    'skype':skype,
    'email':email
    })

    redirect_url = reverse('create')
    message = messages.success(request, "You successfully updated your profile!")
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
else:

    form = UserDataForm({
        'last_name': func['last_name'],
        'first_name':func['first_name'],
        'email':func['email'],
        'skype':func['skype'],

        })

    message = messages.success(request, "You just loaded your profile initial data")
return render_to_response('create.html', {'form': form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you call twice the `form.save()` statement. Once at the beginning of the method, here:

```
    updated_field = form.save()
```

Another one at the end:

```
    if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```